# Replace textNode value substring with strong node and output to document

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to bold words inside a string using vanilla javascript (Stricly, no jQuery allowed), so far I have something like this but the string outputs `[object HTMLElement]` in the middle of the string.

```
const fullString = "This is a sentence, please bold the words sentence";
const wordToBold = "sentence";

const boldenWord = (word, fullstring) => {
  word = word.toLowerCase();

  const boldTextNode = document.createElement("strong");

  const textNode = document.createTextNode(word);

  boldText.appendChild(textNode);

  fullstring = fullstring.replace(keyword, boldText);

  return fullstring;
}


const ul =  document.createElement('ul');
const li = document.createElement('li')


const liText = document.createTextNode(boldenWord(wordToBold,fullString))

li.appendChild(liText);
ul.appendChild(li);


const outerUL = document.querySelector("#myUlOuter ul")
```

This ends gives me the following output

```
<ul>
<li>This is a [object HTMLElement], please bold the words [object HTMLElement]</li>
</ul>
```

> This is a [object HTMLElement], please bold the words [object HTMLElement]

but I'm after

```
<ul>
<li>This is a <strong>sentence</strong>, please bold the words <strong>sentence</strong></li>
</ul>
```

> This is a **sentence**, please bold the words **sentence**

Comment: Your example is a bit confusing.  You're referencing "boldText" and "resultTitle", but I can't see where they are declared. That aside, the fact that in your final result you're seeing [object HTMLElement] means that the object being incorporated into the full string is an actual document element, not just a string of text as you probably think you're getting.  (And then, because it's being concatenated with some other text, javascript is doing a .toString(), which results in the [object HTMLElement] output.)  I suspect you need to call .outerHTML() on the "bold" node to get the desired result

Comment: @Craig ,Christ, how silly can I be! that's the exact proble, & now that I have that outputting `<strong>sentence</strong>`, i've realised I didn't need to create `liText` as a textNode but simply the string and then `li.innerHTML = liText`
Yes, I realised, I made a few mistakes in the question - I've updated it now but also found the solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A text string is not of itself bold or otherwise. When rendered as HTML it can produce bold text if it contains `<strong> </strong>` tag pairs surrounding text to be rendered in bold.

---

The first option is to create an HTML source string by inserting `strong` tags around word or words in a text string, followed by inserting the HTML into the document. To ensure valid HTML you should also change any `<`, `>` or `&` characters in the input string to HTML character enties `&lt;`, `&gt;` or `&amp;`.

---

The second option is to create textNodes for portions of the string to be rendered as plain text, interspersed with HTMLElement nodes with tagName "strong".

A `strong` element for with specified text content can be created along the lines of

```
const strongElem = textContent => {
   let strong = document.createElement("strong");
   strong.textContent = textContent;
   return strong;
};
```

The exercise now becomes

- create an output element
- parse or scan the input string into successive parts of normal and bold text.
- create text nodes for normal text and append them as child nodes of the output element, and
- create strong nodes for bold text and, again, append them as child nodes of the output element in the same order as encountered.

You may still wish to change  `<`, `>` or `&` characters in the *word to be in bold* to their character entity equivalents.

---

Hoping this helps completing the assignment.